# Debugging error in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Debugging error :

> Error while trying to run project.
>   Could not load file or assembly '
>   consoleapp2' or one of its
>   depenencies. The module was expected
>   to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: derpderp, what's your question

Comment: What is your environment like? What kind of project are you running? What's in the assembly "consoleapp2"? Does your code compile?

Answer (score 0):

The "module was expected to contain an assembly manifest" part of the error suggests that you may be trying to link to an unmanaged executable.

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/9ad17869-63cc-4529-bfaf-9099db500e0d) suggests the error can be caused by linking to assemblies with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an assembly that's not there, or is there, but can't load. Could be a couple of things. Be sure to include it and its dependencies into your solution, and make sure none of your files have the same name (regardless of extensions), as dave suggested.